# resolve behaves different in REPL and -main

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, resolve

I have the following code

```
(ns clojure-noob.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main [& args]
    (defn A [x] (str x "a"))
    (println (A "."))                        ; .a
    (println A)                              ; some object
    (println (symbol "A"))                   ; just A
    (println (resolve(symbol  "A")))         ; nil
    (println ((resolve(symbol  "A")) "."))   ; nullpointer exception
)
```

If I enter the lines (starting with `(defn A ...`) one by one in repl, they behave as expected. The last one

```
    (println ((resolve(symbol  "A")) "."))
```

calls A on "." i.e. appends the letter a.
But the whole thing called with `lein run` in leiningen gives `nil` on the second last and a null pointer exception on the last line, i.e. `resolve` does not resolve as expected.

What am I doing wrong? What is the difference between `lein repl` and `lein run` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that your *current namespace* is different when `resolve` is being evaluated in `lein repl` vs. `lein run`, and `resolve` works on the *current namespace.* The `resolve` docstring:

> same as (ns-resolve *ns* symbol) or (ns-resolve *ns* &env symbol)

`*ns*` is a binding to whatever the current namespace is.

You can see the difference by adding `(println "current ns is" *ns*)`.

Using `ns-resolve` and passing the namespace explicitly will make your code work in both cases:

```
(println (ns-resolve 'clojure-noob.core (symbol "A")))
(println ((ns-resolve 'clojure-noob.core (symbol "A")) "."))
```

As an aside, you typically don't see *nested* `defn` i.e. your `A` function could be defined outside/before `-main` function.